# How to Customize Breadcrumbs in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, css, breadcrumbs

I want to customize `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs` class in magento 2.
How can i change some text and style of breadcrumbs with custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Custom module for extend Breadcrumbs in Magento2: https://github.com/gr33nart/m2_greenart_breadcrumbs

Printscreen: https://goo.gl/GwoZPW

Comment: [@Chandra Kumar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54044/chandra-kumar) My answer helped you?